# Validate script's argument by file extension?

Tags: linux, validation, shell, arguments

**I am writing a script which you can pass a file name into as an argument and it'll only run if it's a certain file extension.**

```
flac2mp3 "01 Song.flac"
```

or

```
flac2mp3 "01 Song.FLAC"
```

I know there a lot of scripts out there showing you how to convert flac to mp3, but this is my script and I want to learn how to write the script using this method.

It's so I can learn arguments and for when I feel like converting only 1 individual file. (for multiple files I just wrote a for loop with *.flac inside the script)

I just want to learn how to check if the $1 argument contains *.[Ff][Ll][Aa][Cc]

Here's what I cobbled up together from the internet so far (which I know is embarrassingly wrong but I wanted to show what I was going for) :

```
#!/bin/bash
#flac2mp3

if [ -z $1 ] && [[$1 !=~ *.[Ff][Ll][Aa][Cc]]];then echo "Give FLAC File Name"; exit 0;fi

OUTF=${1%.flac}.mp3

ARTIST=$(metaflac "$1" --show-tag=ARTIST | sed s/.*=//g)
TITLE=$(metaflac "$1" --show-tag=TITLE | sed s/.*=//g)
ALBUM=$(metaflac "$1" --show-tag=ALBUM | sed s/.*=//g)
GENRE=$(metaflac "$1" --show-tag=GENRE | sed s/.*=//g)
TRACKNUMBER=$(metaflac "$1" --show-tag=TRACKNUMBER | sed s/.*=//g)
DATE=$(metaflac "$1" --show-tag=DATE | sed s/.*=//g)

flac -c -d "$1" | lame -m j -q 0 --vbr-new -V 0 -s 44.1 - "$OUTF"
id3 -t "$TITLE" -T "${TRACKNUMBER:-0}" -a "$ARTIST" -A "$ALBUM" -y "$DATE" -g "${GENRE:-12}" "$OUTF"

done
```

Please and Thank Your for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
shopt -s nocasematch

if [[ $1 == *flac ]]; then
    echo "ok"
fi
```

This is case insensitive.

**EDIT**

```
$ LANG=C help shopt
shopt: shopt [-pqsu] [-o] [optname ...]
    Set and unset shell options.

    Change the setting of each shell option OPTNAME.  Without any option
    arguments, list all shell options with an indication of whether or not each
    is set.

    Options:
      -o        restrict OPTNAMEs to those defined for use with `set -o'
      -p        print each shell option with an indication of its status
      -q        suppress output
      -s        enable (set) each OPTNAME
      -u        disable (unset) each OPTNAME

    Exit Status:
    Returns success if OPTNAME is enabled; fails if an invalid option is
    given or OPTNAME is disabled.
```

If you run `shopt` alone in a shell, you will see al options available :

```
$ shopt
autocd          on
cdable_vars     on
cdspell         off
checkhash       off
checkjobs       off
checkwinsize    off
cmdhist         on
compat31        off
compat32        off
compat40        off
compat41        off
direxpand       off
dirspell        off
dotglob         on
execfail        off
expand_aliases  on
extdebug        off
extglob         on
extquote        on
failglob        off
force_fignore   on
globstar        on
gnu_errfmt      off
histappend      on
histreedit      off
histverify      off
hostcomplete    off
huponexit       off
interactive_comments    on
lastpipe        off
lithist         off
login_shell     off
mailwarn        off
no_empty_cmd_completion off
nocaseglob      off
nocasematch     off
nullglob        off
progcomp        on
promptvars      on
restricted_shell        off
shift_verbose   off
sourcepath      on
xpg_echo        off
```

To know what does all these options :

```
man bash | less +/'^SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS'
```

then search `shopt from within this section.

Comment: Thank you! 

So the builtin shopt is just for the case insensitive? All I had to do was:
    if [[ $1 != *flac ]]
and put it inside double square brackets?

Comment: Thank You. I just realized that shopt means "shell options". I'll look up shopt and bash settings.  I'm hoping it's mentioned in the book I'm reading.  "A Practical Guide to Linux Commands, Editors and Shell Programming"